# What is the difference between OnChanges and DoCheck in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Difference between them seems to be very confusing to me.
What is difference between them and exactly when they are called

Answer (score 72, accepted):

- `ngOnChanges()` (`OnChanges`) is called when a value bound to an input has changed so you can run custom code when an input has changed.
- `ngDoCheck()` (`DoCheck`) is called when change detection runs so you can implement your custom change detection action.

Comment: actually i am confused by the term "change detection runs", when angular checks for change detection

Comment: Angular uses zone.js and patches all kinds of async apis `addEventListener`, `setTimeout`, ... Every time an event handler or some other async code is completed or when change detection is invoked explicitely by some code, Angular2 runs change detection. This is when `ngDoCheck` is called. `ngOnChanges` is only called when change detection detects a change that requires an input to be updated.

Comment: ngDocheck called every time when there is change detection cycle runs while ngOnChange only fire when there is a change in bound model property in component

Comment: @RajBahadurSingh isn't this exactly what my answer says?

Comment: Actually, the answer could be much better if you would mention that ngOnChanges only triggers when the actual instance of the object changes

Comment: @YannicHamann I assume you mean that Angular does not recognize a change if only a property of a bound value was changed (instead of the new value being a different instance).

Comment: Yeah exactly, doesn't that mean (maybe I am confusing terminology) that the part of the change management for angular that invokes ngOnChanges() only detects if the bound value changes its object instance?

Comment: Yes that is what it means. My answer follows on that. When Angular recognizes the value has changed, it updates the binding and that causes `ngOnChanges` to be called.

Comment: angular folks need to add these statements. Thanks

Answer (score 44):

I was playing with these two and found some interesting stuff that worth sharing :

`ngDoCheck()`:

This will get called every time one of Zone hooks get called,

**How?**

Angular2 uses NgZone, which as @Gunter said as well, has monkey patched all the async events inside the browser, you can think of it like ;

```
var originalTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function(callback,time) {
    originalTimeout(callback,time);

    // notify Angular that a setTimeout is fired
    // e.g run ngDoCheck() for components
}
```

So every time you run `setTimeout`, you're actually calling above function which is monkey patched the original `setTimeout`.

> **Disclaimer**: Above code is completely abstract and in Zonejs you're not gonna find it, but I just wanted to somehow show what it means when they say "Zone has patched all the async functions and have hooks in them";

Anyways, so every time you run a `setTimeout` (or any other async function), when it's finished, `ngDoCheck` will be called.

So it means angular just checks to see if there has been a change in the model or any of the @inputs or not.

**When this is handy?**

`ngDoCheck` becomes handy if your component's `ChangeDetectionStrategy` is OnPush, meaning that it's only gonna update the view if any of the @Inputs references has been changed.

Which there are some cases that you want to use OnPush but you want to do some manual updating on every check.

Check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rbfK1GM8NpLxajyRBvbe?p=preview) .

You'll find that even if the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` of the `on-push-test` component is `OnPush`, when we click on mutate food and that mutates the *foods* list, I'll run the `markForCheck` inside the `ngDoCheck` and update the view after a dummy `if` condition.

**So this means, this function will get called A LOT !!! so be careful what you're putting inside it.**

So in short :

`ngDoCheck` : this function will get called every single time an event has fired in the app that may cause a change, but not necessarily is considered a change.

---

`ngOnChanges`

This will only and only get called if there has been a reference change in any of the @Inputs bindings, regardless of the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` of the component.

So if we mutate foods array like this :

```
this.foods.push({value: 'steak-3', viewValue: 'Fish'});
```

The `ngOnChanges` will not get called, but if we update the reference like this:

```
this.foods = [{value: 'steak-3', viewValue: 'Fish'}];
```

It'll get called.

Answer (score 31):

First of all Kudos to the above answers.
I am adding a use-case for both of the functions which I have faced personally.

`ngOnChanges() (OnChanges)`: to detect changes for variables passed by value

`ngDoCheck() (DoCheck)` : to detect changes for variable passed by reference such as `arrays`, which are not detected by `ngOnChanges()` as the old value and the new value have the same reference

Answer (score 4):

`ngDoCheck` is called on the child component when the parent component is being checked.
`ngOnChanges` is triggered every time when the Angular detected a change to the data-bound input property.
`ngOnChanges` does not fire when the input property is an array/object because Angular uses dirty checking to compare the properties.
`ngDoCheck` does fire when the input property is an array/object like customer class etc.

Comment: What's `ngOnCheck `, I do not see it mentioned in the official Angular documentation, https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence ?

Answer (score 1):

ngDoCheck(): will be called every time a change detection system detects a change
ngOnChanges(): will be called only when a child component receives a value from parent component using @input decorator.