# Angular ngDoCheck() gets called even with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

Lets say i have a component structure like this:

```
AppComponent
    HeaderComponent
    ContentComponent
        TodosComponent
            TodoComponent
```

If I set HeaderComponent's `changeDetection` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and change something in TodoComponent, still HeaderComponent's `ngDoCheck()`, `ngAfterViewChecked()` and `ngAfterContentChecked()` gets triggered.

What am I missing? Does ngDoCheck gets triggered anyway? If yes, how to determine if a component was checked by ChangeDetection?

Comment: It depends on what is being changed, but you should look at these two links as they explain what can happen in detail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629828/what-is-the-difference-between-onchanges-and-docheck-in-angular-2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795634/angular-2-change-detection-and-changedetectionstrategy-onpush.
Based on these it seems that `ngDoCheck` gets triggered regardless of your change detection strategy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct behavior. The article [If you think `ngDoCheck` means your component is being checked — read this article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5) explains the behavior in great details. Here is the short version.

The `ngDoCheck` is triggered **before the component is being checked**. This is done to allow you to perform some custom logic and then mark the component for a check. You know that Angular tracks `@Input`s by object references but you can use `ngDoCheck` to make your custom tracking. Here is the simple example:

```
Component({
   ...,
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
MyComponent {
   @Input() items;
   prevLength;
   constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.prevLength = this.items.length;
   }

   ngDoCheck() {
      if (this.items.length !== this.prevLength) {
         this.cd.markForCheck();
      }
   }
```

Please bear in mind that `ngDoCheck` is triggered only for the top level component with the strategy `OnPush`. It's not triggered for this components children.

Also it is correct that `ngAfterViewChecked` will be triggered for the component even if now checking was done. This is by design as well.

I highly recommend you to read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f), specifically `Exploring the implications` section. It shows the order of operations you're looking for.

Also read  [Why do we need `ngDoCheck`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42807309/2545680).

Comment: But how to determine if it was actually checked and my changeDetectionStrategy is working fine?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Your component will be checked only if the `@Input` change. why do you need to know that the component was checked. also I highly recommend reading the article to understand the process

Comment: Yes but there is no possibility to confirm it was not checked? I can only know but not be sure. I read a lot of articles and i am pretty sure how this works and what events trigger CD. Im just looking for a way to verify a component has run through CD or not.

Comment: you have a few options. for example, you can modify some value used in the template in the HeaderComponent using timeout - it won't be reflected in the view. Other option is to listen for lifecycle hooks on children components - no lifecycle hooks will be triggered for them

Comment: Thats the only 2 possibilities i can think of, too. Maybe there should be a new lifecycle-hook?

Comment: why do you need to check that? if just to make sure that the strategy works those two options should be enough

Comment: @Mick Just add some code that is executed on every checking view like `{{ testChecking() }}` in template with OnPush and observe

Comment: @Mick Or open `HeaderComponent.ngfactory.js` and set breakpoint on `updateDirectives` or `updateRenderer` function but first you need to read more about it in articles that Maximus has written

Comment: @Mick Or if you know source code well set breakpoint here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L612 and observe `view.component`. I prefer watching for `ngfactory.js`

Comment: @yurzui, I was going to recommend the breakpoint in sources first but then I decided to stick to `no sources` approach) Besides it's all shown in the article