# Angular - why lifecycle hooks are called on detached component?

Tags: angular, android-lifecycle

Let's say **app component** has inside **a component** that has inside **b component** and **a** and **b** components are detached and every component has a button. Why then each time when I click any button I get this in the console? I thought that ngAfterContentChecked and ngAfterViewChecked should not be called in **a component** because it is detached? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afkaxc

```
ngDoCheck App
ngAfterContentChecked App
ngDoCheck A
ngAfterContentChecked A
change detection beginning app
ngAfterViewChecked A
ngAfterViewChecked App
change detection beginning app
```

Comment: Events still trigger CD even if they occur in detached views. Take a look at [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/), "OnPush change detection and event handlers" section

Comment: I know but why ngAfterContentChecked and ngAfterViewChecked are called in the detached component (a) but change detection in (a) component has not occurred (the view for a comppnent has not be re-rendered)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular ngDoCheck() gets called even with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521588/angular-ngdocheck-gets-called-even-with-changedetectionstrategy-onpush)