# Is there a way to llog every time change detection runs on component level?

Tags: angular

Is there a way to log every time Angular runs change detection on the component?

for example I have three components: `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

when change detection runs it will `console.log`:

```
Run change detection on `foo`.
Run change detection on `bar`.
Run change detection on `baz`.
```

So this way I'll know which component is running change detection.

Comment: You can do it in ngOnChanges life cycle hook

Comment: OnChanges will only trigger when an @Input changes..

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, implement [DoCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck) and console.log inside it.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements DoCheck {
  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log("Change detection reached MyComponent")
  }
}
```

**Explanation**:
the `ngDoCheck` method is actually your extension of the component **dirty check**. Its code will be compiled and added to the factory of your component in the change detection part.

Notice: If you don't see the console.log then the change detection haven't reach your component. This might happen for example of you use `onPush` strategy and the inputs of the parent component haven't change.

Answer (score -2):

**OnCheck**

The ngDoCheck method serves the purpose of enhancing the component's dirty checking mechanism, allowing you to detect when change detection is triggered for the component.

However, it is crucial to note that this approach has certain limitations when it comes to components defined with the OnPush strategy. In such cases, the ngDoCheck method is also invoked in the top-level component to ensure that no custom checks are defined by the user.

Nonetheless, for the child components, this can serve as an indication of whether change detection was activated for them.
(see [Angular ngDoCheck() gets called even with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521588/angular-ngdocheck-gets-called-even-with-changedetectionstrategy-onpush))

**Binding**

add a binding to a function, similar to the following:

```html
    <span>{{ checkChangeDetection() }}</span>
```

then in ts file

```
checkChangeDetection() {
    console.log("checked!)
}
```