# What is the difference between OnChanges and OnPush in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Similar to this question, [What is the difference between OnChanges and DoCheck in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629828/what-is-the-difference-between-onchanges-and-docheck-in-angular-2)

Difference between them seems to be very confusing to me. What is the difference between Onchanges and OnPush ?

Comment: May [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/) can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnChanges, is a life-cycle hook that is called when any of the data-bound property of a directive changes. ChangeDetectionStrategy is the strategy that the default change detector uses to detect changes.

There are two ChangeDetectionStrategies in Angular.

```
enum ChangeDetectionStrategy {
  OnPush: 0
  Default: 1
}
```

OnPush is a type of OnChanges. By default Angular uses the ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default change detection strategy.

**ngOnChanges()**
If you do not specify, Angular will apply the default change detection method which detects changes for entire components whenever changes are made. The default strategy doesn’t assume anything about the application, therefore every time something changes in our application, as a result of various user events, timers, XHR, promises, etc., a change detection will run on all components.

**OnPush**

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

When using OnPush detectors, then the framework will check an OnPush component when any of its (only its) input properties changes, when it fires an event, or when an Observable fires an event. From my understanding OnPush is a simple way for making the applications faster.

[Change detection strategies](https://itnext.io/onpush-change-detection-for-faster-angular-apps-f5d6dccea589)

[Here you go for more detailed explanation](https://medium.com/@mikyung.lee11/angular-change-detection-default-vs-onpush-606daf9ea999)

Comment: hi Swinkaran, gave points and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**onchange**

By default Angular uses the ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default change detection strategy.

**onpush**

We can set the ChangeDetectionStrategy of our component to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush .
This tells Angular that the component only depends on its @inputs() ( aka pure ) and needs to be checked only in the following cases:

1️⃣ The Input reference changes.
By setting the onPush change detection strategy we are signing a contract with Angular that obliges us to work with immutable objects (or observables as we’ll see later).

The advantage of working with immutability in the context of change detection is that Angular could perform a simple reference check in order to know if the view should be checked. Such checks are way cheaper than a deep comparison check.
Let’s try to mutate an object and see the result.